# reached end of file while parsing,,

Tags: java, file, parsing

I cant seem to get this error to go away. it says that on the last line: reached end of file while parsing, can anyone help me here?

```
class scanner
{ 
    class Factorial
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            int n, c, fact;

            System.out.println("Enter an integer to calculate it's factorial");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            n = in.nextInt();

            if ( n < 0 )
                System.out.println("Number should be non-negative.");
            else
            {
                for ( c = 1 ; c <= n ; c++ )
                    fact = fact *c;

                System.out.println("Factorial of "+n+" is = "+fact);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Start using indentations. It will let you spot errors more easily. Also do you really want to have nested classes (currently Factorial is inside scanner). Another thing: don't call your class with name that is already used like in your case Java already have `Scanner` class - in package `java.util` which you forgot to import - so your class shouldn't be called `scanner`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a bracket "}" at the end, that's why it throws that error.

Corrected code syntax, solving other errors too.

EDIT: as @Pshemo said, you don't need the "class scanner" so I commented that, but you can delete what is commented for real

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//public static class scanner
//{ 
    public static class Factorial
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            int n, c, fact;

            System.out.println("Enter an integer to calculate it's factorial");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            n = in.nextInt();

            if ( n < 0 )
                System.out.println("Number should be non-negative.");
            else
            {
                for ( c = 1 ; c <= n ; c++ )
                fact = fact *c;

                System.out.println("Factorial of "+n+" is = "+fact);
            }
        }
    }
//}
```

Comment: umn, ok, I put it there, but now im getting another different type of error, it is : Line: 10
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class scanner.Factorial

Line: 10
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class scanner.Factorial

Line: 5
Illegal static declaration in inner class scanner.Factorial
  modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations

Comment: read the errors. You need to import "Scanner" library. And you need to declare classes as "public static" if you want a "public static void main()". I have update my answer solving these errors too.

Comment: There is no such a thing as `static outer class` (unless it is also inside other class) so you should skip `static` in `scanner` class declaration.

Comment: @Pshemo that's right. I think he misunderstood "import scanner" with "class scanner". So I edited my answer